# place the symbol

Tags: python, numbers, text-manipulation

to add certain symbol after every three got splited lines Something like that?? -

```
print('@'.join(st_text[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(st_tex), 3)))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "smth going wrong."?

Comment: this one after three symbols in text.. not after every third coma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks if there are three or more commas in the text. If it is, it splits the text into 4 parts, then concats the 3 first parts and adds an `@` before the third comma and redo the same process with the remaining text (4th part):

```py
text = "Reading practice to help you understand simple texts and find specific information in everyday material. Texts include emails, invitations, personal messages, tips, notices and signs. Texts include articles, reports, messages, short stories and reviews."
result = ''
while len(splitted := text.split(',', 3)) == 4:
    result += splitted[0] + ',' + splitted[1] + ',' + splitted[2] + '@,'
    text = splitted[3]
result += text
```

```py
result == "Reading practice to help you understand simple texts and find specific information in everyday material. Texts include emails, invitations, personal messages@, tips, notices and signs. Texts include articles, reports@, messages, short stories and reviews."
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
print('@,'.join([str(','.join(st_text[i:i + 3])) for i in range(0, len(st_text), 3)]))
```

Comment: I was thinking how to generate into str. I got. THANK YOU!